# Simultanous complex equations

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Given the following equations:

\begin{array}
 ((\sin \beta \cos \alpha - i\sin \beta \sin \alpha)b + a\cos \beta = a \\
(\sin \beta \cos \alpha + i \sin \beta \sin \alpha)a - b\cos \beta = b
\end{array}
with the condition that $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$. How does it follow that $$a = \cos(\frac{\beta}{2})e^{i \theta_a} ~~~\text{and}~~~b = \sin(\frac{\beta}{2})e^{i \theta_b}?$$

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What are $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equations
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin\beta\cdot e^{-i\alpha}b+(\cos\beta-1)a&=&0,\\
\sin\beta\cdot e^{i\alpha}a-(\cos\beta+1)b&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
after using the double angle formulas becomes
\begin{eqnarray}
2\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\left(\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\cdot e^{-i\alpha}b-\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\cdot a\right)&=&0,\\
2\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\left(\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\cdot e^{i\alpha}a-\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\cdot b\right)&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
which is equivalent to the single equation
$$
\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\cdot e^{i\alpha}a-\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\cdot b=0=
\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\alpha}\sin\frac{\beta}{2} & -\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}
$$
that has a solution
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}\cos\frac{\beta}{2}\\e^{i\alpha}\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is straightforward to show that $|a|^2+|b|^2=|\lambda|^2$ and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You state 'that has a solution', but this is not the only solution so why are we only considering this solution?

Comment: @JohnDoe Perhaps I should have said "that has *the* solution". It is the only solution. The equation  $\begin{bmatrix}c_1 & c_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=0$ is the line equation in $\Bbb C^2$ in the affine form (all vectors that are orthogonal to the normal vector $c$). The solution is the same line in the parametric form.

Comment: @JohnDoe In other words, assuming for simplicity $c_1,c_2\ne 0$ we can rewrite $c_1x+c_2y=0$ as $\frac{x}{c_2}=-\frac{y}{c_1}$ and call this fraction $\lambda$. Then $x=\lambda c_2$ and $y=-\lambda c_1$.

Comment: If you have a chance please have a look at [my other post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210064/simplification-of-binomial-coefficients).