# Simplification of binomial coefficients

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Quick question, does anyone know how to simplify this series of binomial coefficients?

$$\sum_{m = 0}^{N} \binom{N}{m}^{\frac{1}{2}} \binom{N}{m+1}^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Maybe Ramanujan knew something about it.

Comment: @user254665: I do not get it: what Ramanujan (with his nested radicals, I presume) has to do with the current question?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. I mean that you might belong in his league if you can find an elegant formula.

Comment: I cannot see how one would call that a product of binomial coefficients. Looks like a sum to me, and not even one of products of binomial coefficients.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You are right I changed it but forgot to edit that part. Will do so now.

Answer (score 1):

I won't expect any nice closed form for the given sum, but the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives a reasonable upper bound:
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\sqrt{\binom{N}{m}}\sqrt{\binom{N}{m+1}} \leq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\binom{N}{m}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\binom{N}{m+1}\right)} = 2^N-1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the application of Cauchy-Schwarz but how did you get the $2^N - 1$? And why is the upper bound on the series $N-1$ rather than $N$?

Comment: @JohnDoe: both inner summations give $2^N-1$, because there is one binomial coefficient of the row of Pascal's triangle missing, and that coefficient equals $1$.